# Error with uninstalling Eclipse SDK when it is bugged

Tags: release-hera, sideload

**Backstory:** I installed Eclipse SDK as in Windows 10, I use this software and use it. Eclipse broke and I wanted to reinstall. But uninstalling resulted in an error.

**Problem:** I wanted to uninstall the flatpak but it resulted in this error. Can you help fix this error, I want to reinstall it as Eclipse is super broken and I can't use it to make my Minecraft plugin I make on my free time.

```
Application state not set as installed in AppCenter for package: Eclipse SDK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal application, and run first `flatpak list`. This command should list all flatpak installed applications. Notice the name of eclipse there and run 
`flatpak uninstall name_of_eclipse` or `flatpak remove name_of_eclipse`.